# Grid View check the value is exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list "ddlMitchelLandscape2" ,when add button triggers ,i add the selected item value in to gridview.

I am stuck here ,how to check the gridview, before add the value to grid view. The selected item is already exist in grid view or not when the add button is triggered .

Some one help me how to check the value is exist in gridview before add it to gird view please ?

```
  protected void btnAddMitchellLandscape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //validate to make sure Mitchell Landscape is entered
        if (!ValidateMitchellPage())
            return;


        Assessment objAssessment = (Assessment)Session[Session_CurrentAssessment];
        if (ddlMitchelLandscape2.GetSelectedItemValue > 0)
        {
            if (lblMitchellID.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                //add
                AssessmentEntity objAssessmentEntity = new AssessmentEntity();
                Assessment.tblMitchellLandscapeIDRow row =
                    objAssessment.tblMitchellLandscapeID.NewtblMitchellLandscapeIDRow();
                row.MitchellLandscapeID = ddlMitchelLandscape2.GetSelectedItemValue;
                row.MitchellLandscapeName = ddlMitchelLandscape2.GetSelectedItemText;

            }
            else
            {
                //Add button not visible when its not a new row
                ctrlHeader.ShowError("Error: Unknown error");
                return;
            }
            //refresh data bound table
            PopulateMitchellDetailsToForm(ref objAssessment);
            //clear after save
            btnClearMitchellLandscape_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
```

ValidateMitchellPage()

```
  private bool ValidateMitchellPage()
    {
        litMitchellError.Text = string.Empty;
        if (ddlMitchelLandscape2.GetSelectedItemValue <= 0)
            litMitchellError.Text = "Please select Mitchell Landscape";

        if (litMitchellError.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            litMitchellError.Visible = false;
            return true;
        }
        litMitchellError.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }
```

DataBind to grid view

```
        private void PopulateMitchellDetailsToForm(ref Assessment objAssessment)
    {
        Assessment.tblMitchellLandscapeIDRow[] MlData
            = (Assessment.tblMitchellLandscapeIDRow[])objAssessment.tblMitchellLandscapeID.Select("SaveType <> " + Convert.ToString((int)EnumCollection.SaveType.RemoveOnly));
        this.gvMitchellLandscape.DataSource = MlData;
        this.gvMitchellLandscape.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: What is not working here ? Any error/exception that you are receiving ?

Comment: sorry,i have no idea how to check the gridview when the add button is triggered

Comment: Loop through grid view and check if the value is the same as the one that is entered.

Comment: you can check by MlData > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the selected value from the dropdown or combobox in gridview by checking each row.

You can use following code to get row of gridview.

```
bool isValueExist=False;
for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    String val = gridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    if(val == your_drop_down_value)
    {
         isValueExist=True;
         break;
    }
}
```

You have to change the cell number according to your gridview design.